# Text on a curve with consistent length

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, text-object

I have several circle curves that will have different text objects wrapped onto them. Each text object is a string of 64 random characters. The text should exactly fill the size of the circle without any overlap or gap. But different letters are different sizes. Depending on what is randomly put into them, I'll end up with them being too short or long for the circle.

I need a way to keep the text to a consistent length, but the font size needs to stay the same. How can I do this? I suppose if there's a font with all the letters being the same width that would work. But it seems what I really need is for it to adjust the distance between the letters to make sure they fit.

Is there a way to do this? Something like the Fit to Curve option on the Array modifier, but for text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for are [Monospaced Fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Monospace fonts are often used in programming, code editors, command lines or consoles, and have the same space between characters regardless of the glyph width.

Just pick any monospaced version of a font file for use in a Blender text object and it should solve this particular case.

[image]

If you don't have one you can [freely download any from the internet](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace).

This will solve your problem if all strings have the same character count, otherwise if their length varies, you would have to find some other way to calculate and adjust character spacing on a case by case basis depending on resulting width.